# exactly how to read json object sent by php in android?

Tags: android, json

Here is my code to read a json object sent by a web application to android

InputStream instream = entity.getContent();

```
    String result = "";
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(instream, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line1 = null;
        while ((line1 = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line1 + "\n");
        }
        instream.close();
        result = sb.toString();
        Log.i("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
        Log.i("Read from server", result);
        Log.i("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        JSONObject jArray = new JSONObject(result);
    }

    catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.i("------resultat---------", "Errrrrrrrrrrrooooooor");
}
```

but when displaying the result in Logcat it does not display

when execute this line in the code android

> ```
>                    Log.i("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
>       Log.i("Read from server", result);
>       Log.i("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
> ```

it displays this code

```
04-12 09:39:59.980:  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
04-12 09:39:59.980: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
04-12 09:39:59.980:  <html><head>
04-12 09:39:59.980:  <title>403 Forbidden</title>
04-12 09:39:59.980:  </head><body>
04-12 09:39:59.980:  <h1>Forbidden</h1>
04-12 09:39:59.980:  <p>**You don't have permission to access /younes_project/younesservices.php**
04-12 09:39:59.980:  on this server.</p>
04-12 09:39:59.980:  </body></html>
04-12 09:39:59.980: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

please what is the problem for this situation
:):):)

Comment: The problem is that you're getting XML from the server, not JSON... Because, as the error message says, your app doesn't have permission to access the server

Comment: it seems you have some problem in your php file what exactly do you want to do?

Comment: `403 Forbidden` means the page cannot be accessed. nothing to do with json, here

Comment: open your php page in browser...

Answer (score 0):

That's not problem with your code. That's problem with server side script(PHP) or file access permissions . The server is sending an error page to you instead json response. You can contact your PHP developer ask him to change the file access permission file /younes_project/younesservices.php.

Comment: iam the owner to develop the application and the php code I can edit so how to add the permission to access to this file what is the solution

Comment: Open shell and navigate the dir
and type 
chmod 755 younesservices.php

Comment: but the file contains only PHP code,  when execute this file on any browser display in what is no html code

Comment: Have you changed file access permissions?

Comment: I do not know how to change the permission to access the files, change the httpd.conf months please give a link that explains how to make authorization... thks:)

Comment: This is not to do with the httpd.conf
chmod is unix command for more details please click bellow link.
nhttp://www.techonthenet.com/unix/basic/chmod.php